# AnsycTask alway return false

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

Hi i am new to android programming I am making asynctask to collect JSON data. But in debug code always return false even JSON data is parsed.My code is not able to complete the Asynctask and

```
public class WeatherGPS extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Forecast> listItem;
    ForecastAdapter adp;

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather_gps);

        listItem = new ArrayList<Forecast>();
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adp = new ForecastAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_list_item, listItem);
        lv.setAdapter(null);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long Id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), listItem.get(position).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys");

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog pd;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(WeatherGPS.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please wait");
            pd.setTitle("Connecting...");
            pd.show();
            pd.setCancelable(false);

        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse respone = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                int status = respone.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = respone.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("channel").getJSONObject("item").getJSONArray("forecast");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj3 = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Forecast forecast = new Forecast();

                        forecast.setCode(obj3.getString("code"));
                        forecast.setDate(obj3.getString("date"));
                        forecast.setDay(obj3.getString("day"));
                        forecast.setHigh(obj3.getString("high"));
                        forecast.setLow(obj3.getString("low"));
                        forecast.setText(obj3.getString("text"));

                        listItem.add(forecast);

                    }

                    return true;

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return false;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.cancel();
            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from the server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }


}


}
```

I do not get any logcat error

```
11-30 14:19:07.027 8802-8802/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-30 14:19:07.027 8802-8802/? I/art: Late-enabling JIT
11-30 14:19:07.027 8802-8802/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
11-30 14:19:07.104 8802-8802/com.example.weathergps W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.weathergps-2/lib/x86
11-30 14:19:07.302 8802-8830/com.example.weathergps D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-30 14:19:07.400 8802-8830/com.example.weathergps I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-30 14:19:07.541 8802-8830/com.example.weathergps W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-30 14:19:07.541 8802-8830/com.example.weathergps W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabea9fc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-30 14:19:07.602 8802-8830/com.example.weathergps W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-30 14:19:07.602 8802-8830/com.example.weathergps W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabea9fe0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-30 14:19:08.040 8802-8830/com.example.weathergps E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb3fd5410
```

This is my json data:

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "count":1,
      "created":"2015-11-30T02:06:54Z",
      "lang":"en-US",
      "results":{  
         "channel":{  
            "title":"Yahoo! Weather - Nome, AK",
            "link":"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Nome__AK/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USAK0170_f.html",
            "description":"Yahoo! Weather for Nome, AK",
            "language":"en-us",
            "lastBuildDate":"Sun, 29 Nov 2015 4:54 pm AKST",
            "ttl":"60",
            "location":{  
               "city":"Nome",
               "country":"United States",
               "region":"AK"
            },
            "units":{  
               "distance":"mi",
               "pressure":"in",
               "speed":"mph",
               "temperature":"F"
            },
            "wind":{  
               "chill":"29",
               "direction":"0",
               "speed":"0"
            },
            "atmosphere":{  
               "humidity":"78",
               "pressure":"29.44",
               "rising":"0",
               "visibility":"6"
            },
            "astronomy":{  
               "sunrise":"11:19 am",
               "sunset":"4:20 pm"
            },
            "image":{  
               "title":"Yahoo! Weather",
               "width":"142",
               "height":"18",
               "link":"http://weather.yahoo.com",
               "url":"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif"
            },
            "item":{  
               "title":"Conditions for Nome, AK at 4:54 pm AKST",
               "lat":"64.5",
               "long":"-165.41",
               "link":"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Nome__AK/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USAK0170_f.html",
               "pubDate":"Sun, 29 Nov 2015 4:54 pm AKST",
               "condition":{  
                  "code":"14",
                  "date":"Sun, 29 Nov 2015 4:54 pm AKST",
                  "temp":"29",
                  "text":"Light Snow"
               },
               "description":"\n<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/14.gif\"/><br />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />\nLight Snow, 29 F<BR />\n<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />\nSun - Snow. High: 27 Low: 24<br />\nMon - AM Snow Showers. High: 25 Low: 13<br />\nTue - Mostly Sunny. High: 15 Low: 7<br />\nWed - Partly Cloudy. High: 9 Low: 2<br />\nThu - Mostly Cloudy. High: 5 Low: 1<br />\n<br />\n<a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Nome__AK/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USAK0170_f.html\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>\n",
               "forecast":[  
                  {  
                     "code":"16",
                     "date":"29 Nov 2015",
                     "day":"Sun",
                     "high":"27",
                     "low":"24",
                     "text":"Snow"
                  },
                  {  
                     "code":"14",
                     "date":"30 Nov 2015",
                     "day":"Mon",
                     "high":"25",
                     "low":"13",
                     "text":"AM Snow Showers"
                  },
                  {  
                     "code":"34",
                     "date":"1 Dec 2015",
                     "day":"Tue",
                     "high":"15",
                     "low":"7",
                     "text":"Mostly Sunny"
                  },
                  {  
                     "code":"30",
                     "date":"2 Dec 2015",
                     "day":"Wed",
                     "high":"9",
                     "low":"2",
                     "text":"Partly Cloudy"
                  },
                  {  
                     "code":"28",
                     "date":"3 Dec 2015",
                     "day":"Thu",
                     "high":"5",
                     "low":"1",
                     "text":"Mostly Cloudy"
                  }
               ],
               "guid":{  
                  "isPermaLink":"false",
                  "content":"USAK0170_2015_12_03_7_00_AKST"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you should return a `Forecast` (or null) instead of `Boolean`, personally.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a 200 return code from your http request?

Comment: during debug i get " status:200"

Comment: so when i debug all data in the forecast is parsed then it return true but it also return false in doInBackground

Comment: Are you compiling for API23 and running on a emulator for Marshmallow (6.0)? If so, trying using a emulator or real device using 5.1.1 or below, see if you have the same issue.

Comment: yes i m running API23  and i m using emulator lollipop but i also tried running my app on android   lollipop same problem

Answer (score 0):

You're new to android development, and probably the first thing you learned when it comes to multithreading is  `AsyncTasks`. Avoid using them ! They are bound to the activity's life cycle, and they behave really bad when it comes to configuration changes.

Use http://square.github.io/retrofit/ instead, it can deal with background API calls out of the box. Plus, you don't need to browse the json response manually with for loops, `getString("key");` etc.
All you need is a bunch of POJOs that have the same structure as your json response.
Here's a basic tutorial to help you get through :http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

There is also the Volley library from google.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks i will look into it...the reason I am using asynctask is because that is what we were taught in lecture and I have to make project based on it .. I have to follow project requirement

Comment: Asynctasks are only bound to the lifecycle of an activity if programmed that way, what you have said is somewhat misleading.  Asynctasks use the HaMeR framework under the hood and do work well, when implemented well of course. Asynctasks are used extensively throughout Android applications.

Comment: Any experienced android developer avoid using AsyncTasks.I didn't want to dig into it but there are many articles that explain in detail why AsyncTasks are bad. If you want multithreading in your android app, use ThreadPoolExecutors, or, the Bolts framework from facebook, or even better, RxJava.

Comment: My point was: 'They are bound to the activity's life cycle' is misleading, as they are only bound if programmed that way. I can't speak for every experienced Android developer and their thoughts about Asynctask, as I haven't asked them all, so wouldn't want to comment for them..

Comment: I do confirm your point, but, it's just the worst way to deal with multithreading and i'm sure you agree on this. Finally, don't bother speaking to every experienced android developer. Lots of experts from google, square, netflix, etc. are doing their best for the community. Just keep yourself up to date.

Answer (score 0):

If `doInBackground` is returning `false`, an exception must have been thrown somewhere, so I suggest you add `catch (Exception e)` to your catches and narrow down the error from there.

Comment: i donot see any error in logcat and nothing is shown in debug either

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?